# How can I manually reinitialise jscrollpane?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I'm trying to manually reinitialise jscrollpane in my index.php & single.php file after disqus comments have been loaded rather than set autoreinitialise to true when I initialise in my header.php. I'm trying to do so as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(settings).data('jsp');
api.reinitialise();
});
</script>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: WHat is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm using the disqus comments plugin on my site. So that plugin changes the size of my content pane after jscrollpane is initialized. If I set autoreinitialise to true--that takes care of the problem but jscrollpane autoreinitialises every 500ms which causes my scroll bar in most browsers and instances I've tried to constantly refresh, flicker in and out and jump back and forth a bit. So rather than reinitialise on a timer interval--I would like to reinitialise once after the disqus comments are loaded so it sizes correctly but then that's it. No constant reinitialising. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your diquss height aren't ready when the document is ready, try to use a timeout for the reinit, or if disquss has loadingComplete callback use it to reinitialise after it has finished loading using the same lines you wrote in your question should work.